# Valuing a cross currency basis swap using a third currency as a collateral

Tags: interest-rate-swap, collateral, cross-currency-basis

Suppose India and South Africa goes into a cross currency basis swap. But the collateral is specified upon USD. How does one value this type of swaps? Or is it even available directly on the markets?

Answer (score 2):

Multiply each INR (resp. ZAR) leg flow forward value by the corresponding INRUSD (resp. ZARUSD) forward FX, then discount at USD OIS.